# Testing iOS recurring subscription purchases

Tags: ios, storekit, subscriptions

Does anyone know how to test subsequent subscription notifications from StoreKit with recurring subscriptions?  I've tested that the first purchase works correctly but I want to test that I'm handling things correctly once the 2nd month's transaction has been generated and sent to my application.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
[Do auto-renewable subscriptions send an SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased transaction when they auto-renew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396348/do-auto-renewable-subscriptions-send-an-skpaymenttransactionstatepurchased-trans)

paymentQueue:updatedTransaction:  will get called with SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored