# In-App Purchase Auto-Renewable Subscription

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I m developing an application in which user can purchase auto-renewable subscription. When I m trying to buy the feature, I m sending the receipt to the server and getting the server response as status 0. So buying part is working. But problem occurs when user deletes the application and tries to restore the purchase. Lets say that user has purchased any feature on Mar 30 at 20:30. So there is a corresponding expiration date of only 5 minutes (same date at 20:35). This is because in the sandbox environment a 1 month subscription is compressed to 5 minutes time scale.

How to perform restore transaction and how to test restore transaction in sandbox environment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Am I missing something? Just try to purchase the IAP again and it should tell you that you have already purchased it.

Comment: I tried to purchase again and I got the alert message that "You are currently subscribed to this. Your 1 month subscription renews on Mar 30 for $2.99(say). To renew subscription settings or cancel auto-renewal, tap settings". I tried to put NSLog inside the paymentQueue:updateTransactions method and I saw that instead of restore Transaction, failed transaction gets called. So the feature which I have purchased is not being restored.

Comment: same issue here. i've checked [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6149764/1125716) and the answer says it's bug on Apple's part.