# iOS in App purchase Auto-renewal sandbox transaction state

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, subscription

I am testing auto renewing subscription in the sandbox environment and each time it gets renewed, it seems to fire off `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` state.  I did some searching and found this post - [Do auto-renewable subscriptions send an SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased transaction when they auto-renew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396348/do-auto-renewable-subscriptions-send-an-skpaymenttransactionstatepurchased-trans).  The poster replied that auto renewal fires off 'SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored'.  I was wondering if anyone can clarify on why the poster is seeing different state than I am or this have changed?

Also, for my situation that auto renewal fires off `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` state, is there a way I can differentiate whether the user purchase the subscription first time or it is a renewal?